# How to say “ entangled parking space”?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, contract-law, canada

As an official translator, I need to be loyal to the text in such a manner that no words are omitted. In translation of title deeds there’s a section which specifies the metes and bounds of the property in question. In this very part, the specifications of the parking space has been mentioned in to the bargain where there are TWO words meaning “ entangled parking”. To be more specific, there are some old buildings with the capacity of 4 parking space. These four cars, particularly the ones which have been parked ahead, cannot leave the parking since there are two other cars parked behind them! Now how can I translate this?

Comment: I see you have crossposted this to English.SE: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/511169/how-to-say-entangled-parking-space.  Crossposting is generally discouraged on Stack Exchange, but at a minimum, you should make sure that each question contains a link to the other.  Otherwise someone may spend their time writing an answer without realizing that it has already been answered in the other place.

Comment: By the way, what has this got to do with intellectual property?

Comment: I've see a related use in the US as "stacked parking", but it's more than 2 cars in a row--like for a concert venue with limited available parking in the area. Possibly a better word would be "restricted".

Answer (score 2):

This might be a more appropriate question for English.SE.  However a commonly used term for this is **tandem parking**.  See https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/tandem-parking for several citations in legal contexts.

Comment: I've never heard of tandem parking (in the UK).

Comment: Thanks for your time! Isn’t “tandem parking” Australian?

Comment: I'm familiar with the phrase in US English; I don't know whether it's common in Australia.  The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/197451?rskey=EqVUEn&result=1#eid) (paywall, sorry) has citations for *tandem* in the general sense of "one behind the other" from across the English-speaking world, and *tandem garage* citations from Canada and the UK (*Country Life*, 1974.)

Answer (score 1):

In the US, the term "tandem parking" is sufficiently well established so that a document that refers to "tandem parking" is legally clear – in the US. That does not mean that the UK courts will treat such an expression the same way. However, a [brief Google survey](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNShXK9ZHZyLeoKZEfAYReuTU1UtNw%3A1568137753322&ei=GeJ3XeqiE8bK0PEP-YaowAY&q=tandem%20parking%20uk&oq=tandem%20parking%20uk&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.278712.279790..280067...0.2..0.90.261.3......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0.9whksSWxSuw&ved=0ahUKEwiqk_ut6MbkAhVGJTQIHXkDCmgQ4dUDCAo&uact=5) shows "tandem parking" being used in local regulations, in such a way that matches your apparent application. The same seems to hold for [Canada](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNT5RcBf_ipV791zgPyMkoko7XbHbQ%3A1568138392154&ei=mOR3XbuMCeWq0PEP_ciS8AM&q=tandem%20parking%20canada&oq=tandem%20parking%20canada&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6369.10646..10856...0.2..0.106.1643.19j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131i67j0j0i131j0i20i263j0i22i30j33i160.C-_hVUPaGHo&ved=0ahUKEwi7uMre6sbkAhVlFTQIHX2kBD4Q4dUDCAo&uact=5), and I would not hazard a guess about Kenya or India: however, the lack of any examples pointing to this being a recognized term in those jurisdictions suggests that it may be a jurisdiction-specific expression.